# Socket Programming Server With (Ip,port) as variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, serversocket, reverse-shell

HI I want to have my ip and port as user input in my server but i get some errors i cant handle please help me ...

```
import socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


host = input("Enter The Server Ip: ")
port = input("Enter The Server Port: ")

serversocket.bind((host, port)) 

serversocket.listen(10)

while True :
    clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()

    print("Received Connection From %s" % str(address))

    message = 'Connection Established' + "\r\n"
    clientsocket.send(message.encode("ascii"))

    clientsocket.close()
```

Error :

```
line 11, in <module>
    serversocket.bind((host, port))  # Host will be replaced with IP, if changed and not running on host
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

or some times i get :

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Answer (score 1):

`input()` gives you `port` as string but `socket` needs it as `integer`

```
port = int(port)
```

Comment: Doesnt Work Again**********




host = input("Enter The Server Ip: ")
port = input("Enter The Server Port: ")


serversocket.bind((host, int(port))) 




*************
error : line 11, in <module>
    serversocket.bind((host, int(port)))  
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: what address did you use as IP ? It seems you uses wrong value. It has to be your local IP (local IP of your network card or wifi) or `0.0.0.0`. And it is different problem which has nothing to do with previous problem.